# Текст в интерфейсе

Tags: орфография, грамотная-речь, морфология, орфоэпия, оформление-текста

Предисловие: Для входа в банковское приложение есть простой ключ и ключ доступа. Самое главное это - информативность.

Правильно ли добавлять в текст модальные глаголы и начинать предложение с союза? Какой вариант текста лучше? Ну или предложите свой:)

- Осталось 2 попытки для входа с помощью простого ключа. Или войдите с помощью ключа доступа.
- Осталось 2 попытки для входа с помощью простого ключа. Вы можете войти с помощью ключа доступа.
- Осталось 2 попытки для ввода простого ключа. Вы можете войти с помощью ключа доступа.
- Неверный простой ключ. Осталось 2 попытки. Вы можете войти в помощью ключа доступа

Comment: Первый вариант, причём второе предложение разместить с новой строки и часть его сделать ссылкой на форму входа через ключ доступа.

Answer (score 1):

> Правильно ли добавлять в текст модальные глаголы

Это возможно. "Правильно" - это не по сути. А что вы назвали модальным глаголом?

> И начинать предложение с союза?

И это возможно, правда это особый стиль, но для подобных инструкций он вполне приемлем.

> Какой вариант текста лучше?

Сильно зависит от целевой аудитории. Единых рекомендаций тут быть не может. Военный технарь лучше поймет последний, домохозяйка-блондинка - предпоследний, учительница музыки на пенсии, наверное, второй.

> Ну или предложите свой:)

Не стал бы это делать без контекста. Эти ключи где вообще хранятся? 
И какой вообще интерфейс, это диалог идет?

Одно могу сказать: чем короче, тем лучше. Хотя тоже субъективно.

Но если очень настаиваете...

*"Ошибка простого ключа. Осталось **2** попытки. Или введите ключ доступа"*

Comment: Имел ввиду модальный глагол  – можно.

Comment: Если человек при входе в приложение неправильно ввел простой ключ, то показывается диалоговое окно с текстом (про него и идет речь). ЦА – люди 30-40 лет, банковское приложение.

Comment: Еще вариант родился: Неверный простой ключ.  Осталось 2 попытки. Или войдите с помощью ключа доступа.

Comment: "то показывается диалоговое окно с текстом (про него и идет речь)." - я обо всем приложении, чтобы не выпадало по стилю. Там вообще оконный интерфейс? Кнопки какие на окне?

Comment: *Неверный простой ключ. Осталось 2 попытки. Или войдите с помощью ключа доступа* - это, кстати, на мой вкус получше. Но нравится, что у вас все время "войдите" да еще "с помощью ключа". Жаргонизмы все-таки. Не знаю, насколько это стало всеобщим.  Да, кстати, ключ - это пароль? Понимаете, "ключ" - это из области шифрования (открытый-закрытый, например), а пароль - это "***код*** доступа".

Comment: _Там вообще оконный интерфейс?_ – Мобильное приложение, стандартные в iOS – Алерт, Android – попап. _Кнопки какие на окне?_ – OK.

Comment: _Да, кстати, ключ - это пароль?_   Можно войти с помощью простого ключа и ключа доступа, отличие в том что простой ключ состоит из цифр и его удобно набирать, а ключ доступа сложней и вводить трудней. Думал поменять названия, но не нашел альтернатив.

Comment: Это в моем понимании все-таки пароль (и то и другое) или "код доступа".

Comment: *Кнопки какие на окне? – OK* - это не лучший вариант, поскольку воспримется как согласие на ввод "ключа доступа".

Comment: Например – Закрыть?

Comment: *Например – Закрыть?* - не, это вряд ли поможет.  Я не писал для  мобильной техники, а для настольных я бы сделал два окна и/или две кнопки. Но перегружать малый экран - это не комильфо будет. так что скорее всего мое замечание останется стариковским брюзжанием.

Answer (score 0):

Введенный вами простой ключ неверен. Осталось 2 попытки для входа с помощью простого ключа. Вы можете также войти с помощью ключа доступа.